# Probability theory - Combinatorics combined with probability

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory

My question concerns the b) part of this one. the answer from a) is needed and i've provided it below.

At a group assignment in a highschool, 8 students are divided into two equally large groups.

a) How many ways can this division be done? ==> ${8 \choose 4}/2 = 35$.

b) At the next assignment, the same group division is done. What is the probability for a student to be divided into a group with the same three students as last time? = $1/35$

Probability -//- two students from last time?

Probability -//- one students from last time?

Probability -//- none students from last time?

*Note:
I have just been introduced to combinatorics through a probability theory class, hence my knowledge in the area is a bit sketchy. I appreciate all the help I can get, thanks on beforehand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three other students from the original group and four from the other group, and you want the number of equally probable ways of choosing three of them.

- three from original group, zero from other : ${3 \choose 3}{4 \choose 0}$
- two from original group, one from other : ${3 \choose 2}{4 \choose 1}$
- one from original group, two from other : ${3 \choose 1}{4 \choose 2}$
- zero from original group, three from other : ${3 \choose 0}{4 \choose 3}$

then divide by $35$ to give probabilities.  As a check, the probabilities should add up to $1$.

Comment: great stuff Henry thank you! I think I'm getting the picture of how it works for the other questions in my course literature :)